# Getting Silverlight 5 error on IIS with Prism "Resolution of the dependency failed"

Tags: prism, unity-container, silverlight-5.0

I am writing an application that base on silverlight 5 and MVVM framework and Prism library.
I work with prism with unity container.

When I test my application in VS 2010 it works correctly but when I load it on IIS I frequently get this error message :

[image]

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = ...

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you only sometimes get it, but it might be that in your ViewModule you've set up an delegate assigned to a private method - IIRC PRISM event subscription delegates must be public. I think that this is a limitation of Silverlight as it doesn't apply to WPF.